# An abstract factory could not create an instance

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i run this script and i have this Error :

> An abstract factory could not create an instance of
>   doctrine.entitymanager.ormdefault(alias:
>   doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default).

// Get Doctrine entity manager

```
$entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()
        ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```

how can i resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to inject the entity manager to a service through a factory. Imagine you have `entityManager`accessors defined in `YourService`

```
class YourServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) 
    {
         $service = new YourService();
         $service->setEntityManager($sl->get('em'));

         return $service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your doctrine module correctly otherwise your default entity manager cannot be found. 
Use composer to install doctrine module. Then you have to setup configuration correctly. Check how to do this in [the documentation here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule).

After that you should be able to get your entity manager from the service manager like you wrote in your question using:

```
$serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
$entityManager = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```